# Black border around vmware clarity controls

Tags: vmware-clarity

In a recent release of the vmware clarity controls for angular a black border appears around controls when they are clicked. See screen shot below showing a button that's been clicked.

Is this intended as part of the design?
Can this be changed easily?

[image: screen grab showing button click]

Answer (score 4):

This is an accessibility feature for visually impaired, a workaround for this is to add the following code in your styles.scss in order to remove the outline style

```
* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
-webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Nice and clear. Thanks!